# C++ default constructors and default parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, polymorphism, default-parameters

If I have a class containing:

```
foo(); //sets baz to 10
foo(int bar = 0); //sets baz to bar
int baz;
```

Will the 'default' constructor ever be used?

e.g. will:

```
foo qux;
```

default to baz = 0 or 10?

Any difference for:

```
foo * quux = new foo;
```

Comment: Note: these are *both* default constructors.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question, why do people always downvote things  just on the basis of them being simple? From the FAQ - *"Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know."*. Further, this isn't the sort of thing you'll typically find in an introductory C++ book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will the 'default' constructor ever be used?

No, a constructor call specifying no argument will simply be **ambiguous**. The compiler just cannot tell whether the constructor accepting no argument is preferable to the constructor accepting an argument with a default value, or vice versa. **Your code won't compile**.

> Any difference for: `foo * quux = new foo;`

No, same story. Nothing changes if you are creating the object through `new`. The compiler will still be unable to decide which constructor you intend to call.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ambiguous call. As such, I don't think it should even compile. The compiler can't decide whether you meant to call the `foo::foo(int)` constructor or the default constructor, `foo::foo()`.